# IBM Worklight Upgrade from 6.1 to 6.2 -WLUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I upgraded a IBM Worklight studio from 6.1 to 6.2 and apparently everything was ok, but I build an Android environment the main.java file has an error- WLUtils cannot be resolved,  and it came from (import com.worklight.common.WLUtils;), It looks like file structure has been changed and I'm not sure how the structure should be in the latest version (6.2), is it guide or documento how to update the worklight version properly?

I'll appreciate any comment related to this matter

Comment: Try replacing `import com.worklight.common.WLUtils;` with `import com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils;` and let me know if that solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will want to try candreu's suggestion from the comments.
2. Related information about the new structure of the main Java class can be found here:

   - [Understanding the Default startup process in Android-based Hybrid applications](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_start_hybrid_app_android_in_webview.html)

You can create a new application and verify everything is the same.
Also, this should not affect you; did you change anything in this file in your existing application?

Comment: Yes I have a small customization and It was hard for me to migrate to 6.2 especially in IOS, because there was an error in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{ } where it call to NSString *result = [super.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"WL.App.BackgroundHandler.onAppEnteringBackground();"]; which does not exist any more, the only way to figure out  was to open a new worklight project in 6.1, and see if this was generated by default and yes it was, then I deleted and everything works again, Thank you!!